# how to get unique result while using group_concat on column which have comma seprated int values?

Tags: mysql

I have **menu_master** table like this

```
id    name     holder
1     a        1,2,4 
2     b        49,4
```

In the output i only want **1,2,4,49**

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(holder)  
FROM menu_master
```

If I am using group_concat it gives me all result like 1,2,4,49,4.

Comment: The first step is to break these comma-separated lists into a dependent table in which you store one integer per row. This is a problem best solved by normalizing your database.

Comment: While a comma separated list is virtually never a good idea in a database, if the possible values of holders are stored in a table, you could do a join to that table based on FIND_IN_SET() to extract the individual values, and then use GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT....) with those values. But not likely to perform well.